# How to find String in ArrayList which repeats max number of time?

Tags: java, collections

I have an `ArrayList<String>` with one column which is data time seconds etc.

I want to find max number of repetitions for particular date and time(without seconds). It could be, 
e.g. 10 values with following parameters 23.12.2012 21:00:. 
So it must be stated that, say, take only 15 symbols on the left to compare.

The point is that I dont have a value to compare to, because I am not looking for particular value, I am looking for max number of repetitions and of course the value itself* which gave max number of repetitions. `ArrayList` is sorted in descending order, earliest date first, latest last. `ArrayList` size is quite big, 170 million raws.

So, how can I approach this task?

Thanks

Comment: Have a `HashMap` and put the `<date,count>` in it , iterate through the `List` increasing the count of dates in the `Map` if it exists or put a new entry in `Map`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot For 170 million raws? :-o

Comment: @agad Even if you use some library I guess it would have some underlying iteration !

Comment: A combination of grouping and counting will do ... even with 170 Mio Entries

Comment: Off-topic? This place is getting out of control. This is perfectly fine question with a sensible answer. Stop wasting your time closing so many questions. Vote to reopen.

Comment: Or use [Guava Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#frequency(java.lang.Iterable,java.lang.Object)) .

Comment: you don't need hashmap if the list is sorted. Iterate over it counting until you have value changed. Count the new value and replace main counter if number of repetitions exceeded previous one

Comment: @Tala Yes that's correct I assumed it is unsorted and didn't want to sort and then iterate :)

Comment: It's a good question if author provided some code for example.. shouldn't be off-topic IMHO

Comment: @Jason: I agree. I've voted to re-open too. It's an interesting algorithmic question and was looking forward to seeing some good answers. Out of interest I think you can solve this order nlog(n)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I believe, that for sorted list must exist simple algorithm: just convert each date to the representation without seconds and remember the last value with highest number of occurrences.

Comment: @Tala: Why do we need a code sample? The question asked is very clear. We don't need a code sample to answer: scan and count until value changes, compare against current max count, replace if larger than current max, otherwise restart count.

Comment: @Jason sure we don't, just to be sure that author has tried sth himself :)

Comment: @The New Idiot: That's overkill; the list is sorted.

Comment: @Jason Didn't notice that , then a simple iteration with a variable to hold the max count and another to hold the date value is enough :)

Comment: @Tala: Why? Why does he have to have tried something himself? Or more importantly, why does he have to *prove* to me he tried something himself? What do I care? Some questions are so basic it's disappointing when the author clearly performed no research in advance. This is not a difficult question (I'm sure the OP feels otherwise) but it's also not a trivial question.

Comment: @Jason: good point, sortedness makes the solution considerably less interesting. Could do it order(n). Still a valid question though in its current form, imo.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, why have you voted to close this question ?

Comment: @Jason I guess that your comment could be an answer then. If there was some code, the answer could be more readable.

Comment: I can't answer because the question is closed!

Comment: @Jason, You can, then answer is so simple that will fit in comment ;-).

Comment: `ArrayList<String> list;
  String currentMax;
  int maxCount = 0;
  String current;
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   String item = parse(list.get(i));
   if(item.equals(current)) {
    count++;
   }
   else {
    if(count > maxCount) {
     maxCount = count;
     currentMax = current;
    }
    count = 1;
    current = item;
   }
  }` You need to write the `parse` routine to map the `Strings` in the `ArrayList<String> list` to the part that you want to consider that has the date and time but not the seconds.

Comment: I remember answering this yesterday. Surely a homework - should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is very simple. We are going to take advantage of the fact that the `ArrayList<String>` is sorted. We are going to scan the list linearly. We will keep track of the count of the current item. When the item changes to a different item, we compare the current count against the max count seen so far. If it's larger, we replace the max count and max item with item that we were tracking, and then start counting all over again. I will call your `ArrayList<String>` `list`.

```
ArrayList<String> list; 
String currentMax; 
int maxCount = 0;
String current;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String item = parse(list.get(i));
    if(item.equals(current)) {
        count++;
    } 
    else { 
        if(count > maxCount) { 
            maxCount = count; 
            currentMax = current; 
        }
        count = 1;
        current = item;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you will need to write the `parse` routine to map the `String`s in the `ArrayList<String>` list to the part that you want to consider that has the date and time but not the seconds. If your strings are in the format `"dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm*"` the implementation is actually quite simple:

```
static int length = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm".length();
static String parse(String item) {
    return item.substring(0, length);
}
```

Comment: Jason thanks a lot for the solution. I checked it with small file and it works, but when I try to do the same stuff with 8gb csv file, I got following error after 6-7 min of calculationsException in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
 at ddffdf.main(ddffdf.java:18)

Comment: Is the file sorted? If so, I'd suggest not trying to read the entire file into an `ArrayList<String>`, rather, implement exactly the same solution I gave above, but instead of streaming through an `ArrayList<String>`, just stream through the file line by line. You don't need the whole thing to be in memory for the solution that I gave to work. This is, however, assuming that the file is sorted.

Comment: Ok, I tried to implement what was last suggested by Jason, i.e. feed the file directly to the loop. But now I have a problem, now the result is twice as small as it should be. Any ideas why is that so? Processing time decreased significantly though. So I use while loop insted of for loop. while((br.readLine()!=null){String item = br.readLine().substring(0,19) ... the rest as in the code above. Any  suggestions?

Comment: Ok I found a solution. The issue was that I used readline 2 times in my loop, so it checked condition, and than read second line, so workoround - while((line = br.readLine())!=null){String item = line.substring(0,19)... the rest as in the code above.